# How do i include bootstrap class in django forms without widget-tweaks?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a site using django which include forms, but i am not able to find a way to include **form-control** classes in fields. Is there any way to do so?
When i try to install Django-widget-tweaks

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-widjet-tweaks (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-widjet-tweaks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if use a form, you can put over forms.py in definition of form 
using bootstrap for example

from django import forms

```
 from django import forms

 class CommentForm(forms.Form):
 name = forms.CharField(max_length=20, 
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Name'}))
```

example in 
https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/intro_to_django

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `Django-Crispy-Forms` so you can easily use bootstrap without worry too much: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> django-crispy-forms provides you with a |crispy filter and {% crispy
>   %} tag that will let you control the rendering behavior of your Django
>   forms in a very elegant and DRY way. Have full control without writing
>   custom form templates. All this without breaking the standard way of
>   doing things in Django, so it plays nice with any other form
>   application.